# Split M people to N teams with proportion constrains

Tags: algorithm, optimization, split

I have the following problem and I need an algorithm for this. I need to write a program that split M student (in my case they are about 170 student) to N teams (12 teams) with the same number of students in each team as much as possible (in my case 14 or 15 student in a team), and there are 3 constrains.
the first constrain is proportions of female/male between the teams should be equal as much as possible. 
the second constrain is  proportions of outstanding/not outstanding students between the teams should be equal as much as possible. 
the second constrain is  proportions of student live in the city/outside the city between the teams should be equal as much as possible.

I don't need to find the optimal split, but split that good enough and I don't have definition what is good enough, maybe the maximum different  in the proportion can be an input.

I have all the info I need about the students.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Have the three constraints the same level of importance, or they have priorities according to their number (1,2,3)?

Comment: What is more important - to have teams of about the same quality, or to have as many teams of ideal quality as possible? Your task is obviously very badly defined.

Comment: have teams of about the same quality and all constrain in the same level of importance.

Comment: Excellent. And put this info in the question, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here's a general procedure for splitting a group of M students into N teams as evenly as possible:

1. Assign RoundDown(M/N) students to each of the N teams, in any manner.
2. If N is not divisible by M, then N - (M % N) < N "extra" students remain.  Assign each of them to a different team.

After doing this, team sizes differ by at most 1 (some teams got no extra students, while some may have gotten exactly 1 extra student).  Notice that if we have several separate groups of students then we can perform this procedure several times in succession to build up the N teams, and *provided we always add any "extra" students to the smallest teams first*, we will always maintain the property that team sizes differ by at most 1.

You have 3 separate criteria, so each student is in one of 2^3 = 8 groups defined by them (e.g. the group of male, non-outstanding, city students).  So you can simply perform the above procedure 8 times, once for each group.

This will result in:

- Team sizes will differ by at most 1.
- The number of males (or of females, or of outstanding students, etc.) in any two teams will differ by at most 4, since there are 4 groups that include males (males who are/aren't oustanding, and who live/don't live in the city), and we know that for each of these groups, the number of students from that group in a team differs by at most 1.

In practice, it's unlikely that the number of people in any category will differ by as much as 4 between teams.  You can mitigate this even further by being careful about *which* smallest teams get extra students first -- e.g. if you have 3 extra male, non-outstanding, city students left over and there are 7 small teams, you can put them in the 3 teams that have the fewest males (or non-outstanding students, or whichever criterion you want to prioritise).  The same applies if there are more extra students in some group than small teams -- if there are 4 small teams and 9 extra students in some group, the first 4 students have to go to the small teams, but the remaining 5 students can go to whichever or the remaining 8 teams gives the best, say, gender balance.

Comment: one more question. after run this 8 times, how can I combain the all result to ensure I get teams with same size (at most 1 student different)?

Comment: The 2nd, 3rd, ..., 8th runs are adding students to the *same teams* you first created in the 1st run.

Comment: E.g. suppose the first group has 31 students: this will create 7 teams with 3 students and 5 teams with 2 students.  Suppose the second group has 19 students: this will add 1 student to every team, then add 5 students to the 5 smaller teams (bringing them up to 4), then add the remaining 2 students to any 2 teams, so that there are now 10 teams with 4 students and 2 with 5.

Comment: I am tying this and I will let you know how it goes. Thanks!!